# MySQL 5.6 row format changes when changing storage engine from MyISAM to InnoDB

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam, antelope

I am testing an upgrade of all existing MySQL 5.6 tables from `MyISAM` to `InnoDB`.  I converted all row formats to `dynamic` first for all the tables to be on `Barracuda` then running `alter table <tablename> engine = InnoDB` for 16 tables.  12 of the 16 tables changed file formats as well without an alter table command.  I am at a loss to understand this.  I think this may be related to the `.frm` files, but I'm not sure how.  I've checked environment variables:

`innodb_file_format` is showing `Barracuda`

`innodb_file_format_check` is `ON`

A couple of the tables: `Articletranslations` is showing as `compressed`, `pubmedabstractauthors` and `pubmedtranslated` are showing as `compact`. 
The create table statements from tables that I had changed to dynamic file format before changing the storage engine to InnoDB.

Table: articletranslations

```
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `articletranslations` (
  `TranslationID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ArticleID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `language` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `TextContent` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `Name` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `Tags` varchar(1000) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `Detail_Abstract` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `Disclosures` varchar(2000) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `Discussion` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `Acknowledgements` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `D` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `Materials` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `HTMLTopContent` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `Rep_Results` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `Introduction` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `IsMachine` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `DateTranslated` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`TranslationID`),
  KEY `ArticleTranslations_Language_ArticleID` (`language`,`ArticleID`),
  KEY `ArticleTranslations_ArticleID` (`ArticleID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=177437 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED
```

Table: pubmedabstractauthors

```
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `pubmedabstractauthors` (
  `AuthorID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ForeName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `LastName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Initials` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`AuthorID`),
  KEY `names` (`ForeName`,`LastName`,`Initials`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=712515 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Table: pubmedtranslated

```
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `pubmedtranslated` (
  `PMID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ArticleTitle` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `ArticleAbstract` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `LanguageID` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`PMID`,`LanguageID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "a table changes its file format"?

Comment: I'm altering the storage engine and the file format changed without an explicit query run.

Comment: Show us the actual `ALTER` statement used in each case.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that you ran `ALTER TABLE ... ENGINE=InnoDB;` That is a full table rebuild whether you go from MyISAM to InnoDB, or InnoDB to InnoDB (known as the NULL ALTER).

Please note the paragraph from the MySQL 5.7 Docs on [innodb_file_format](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_file_format):

> The innodb_file_format default value was changed to Barracuda in MySQL 5.7.
>
> The innodb_file_format setting is ignored when creating tables that use the DYNAMIC row format. ***A table created using the DYNAMIC row format always uses the Barracuda file format, regardless of the innodb_file_format setting***. To use the COMPRESSED row format, innodb_file_format must be set to Barracuda.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand this correctly -- I understand that MySQL performs a full table rebuild when altering the storage engine.  What is not clear is why would MySQL v. 5.6 change the row format back to compressed from dynamic in this case? Also, one of the tables was changed from dynamic to compact.  Thank you.  :)